# node.js how can I access parameter's member method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node.js and I'm a noob at node.js and javascript.

My server is using express module, and client and server communicate with 'JSON string' format.

```
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('/', function(request, response)
{
    switch(req.body['SERVICETYPE'])
    {
         case 'TEST':
            console.log("test queried : ["+JSON.stringify(request.body)+"]");
            response.send(request.body);
            response.end();
            break;
         case 'TEST_USING_HANDLER':
            console.log("test with handler queried : ["+JSON.stringify(request.body)+"]");
            require('./testhandler.js).TryTest(requst, response);
            break;
    }
});
```

the native 'test' type service is can't using.
because the server must return a **response** to client, but many long-time take function must use handler to send a **response**.(like DB Access)

my testhandler.js is next

```
//testhandler.js
function TryTest(req, res)
{
   var mysql = require('mysql');
   var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    hostname : 'localhost',
        user : 'gameserver',
    password : 'game0',
    database : 'game0'
   });
   connection.connect();
   console.log("findusername = "+req.body['name']);
   connection.query('select * from USE_USERS where name = '+req.body['name'], function(err, rows, cols)
    {           
        if(err) throw err;
        var rtv;
        if(rows[0])
        {
            rtv = {};
            rtv['id'] = rows[0]['id'];
            rtv['name'] = rows[0]['name'];
            rtv['passwd'] = rows[0]['passwd'];
        }
        TestReturn(rtv, req, res);

    });
}


function TestReturn(rtv, req, res)
{
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rtv));
    res.end();
}
```

and the code may feels pseudo(i coded it stackoverflow editor).
but this situation, it returns error
Object # has no method 'send' (on **TestReturn** function)

i can't call **res.send()** or **res.end()** with out of scope that **app.post**'s event handler function.
i thought it may because javascript dosen't have user-control type system(like typecast, as keyword).
how can i write event-driven code on node.js?

Comment: just a minor - `requst` typo in the TEST-USERHANDLE|R - other than that I am not seeing anything yet

Answer (score 3):

Refactor `function TryTest(req, res)` to use a callback.

```
function tryTest(body, callback) {
   // in the event of an error.
   if(database.error) { 
      callback(database.error, null); 
   }

   // if we process successfully 
   callback(null, result);
}
```

*(side-note: in JS, starting a function name with a capital implies that it is an object constructor, in this case your defining a static function so it should be lowercase tryTest() ).*

This new function signature has a couple of benefits.

- It follows nodes convention for asynchronous methods.  This means that many other modules can use this function straight away and other node programmers will immediately understand what it does.
- It now has a single responsibility, writing to the database.  Before it was expected to write to the database and handle sending a response.  We can give that control to the caller by allowing them to pass along a callback, a bit of code to run after we are done with our database operation(s).

So in your main app code:

```
var testHandler = require('./testhandler);

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
    ...
    var body = request.body;
    testHandler.tryTest(body, function(err, rtv){
      err ? res.send(500, json.stringify(err) : res.send(200, JSON.stringify(rtv));
      res.end(); 
    });
}
```